# Docs for "create posts" and "vote up" privileges contradict each other

Tags: discussion, privileges, help-center

Two of the Help Center's privilege pages seem to contradict each other, and I can't tell which one (if either) is correct.

New users, with their 1 point of reputation, automatically earn the "[create posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)".  On that page, under "What happens after I ask a question?", it tells the new user to vote up good answers to his or her question:

> As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer.

But the "[vote up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)" isn't earned until 15 reputation, making this impossible for a low-rep beginner.  The "vote up" page doesn't mention any exceptions to this rule.

I can't find any other docs or Meta posts on the subject, and I can't test a new user's privileges without creating a sock-puppet account.  I see only two likely explanations:

1. The "create posts" page is telling newbies to do something they literally *can't* do.  If so, it should qualify its instructions with something like, "If you've earned the [vote up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you should...".
2. Some exception to the "vote up" privilege allows upvoting answers to your own question, regardless of your rep.  If so, one or probably both of the above pages should mention it, so new users are aware that they *can* grant upvotes, but in that special case only.

I occasionally comment to a new user that they should upvote or accept answers instead of posting "thank you" comments, but I don't want to suggest upvoting if the system won't allow it.

Comment: I don't think you can upvote answers to your own question unless you have the 15 rep.  Reference?

Comment: _Technically,_ they can vote up, it's just in saved as "anonymous feedback" rather than an actual vote. But no, OPs can't upvote answers on their own question unless they have the "vote up" priv.

Comment: @Kendra:  I've never heard of anonymous feedback.  Does an anonymous pseudo-upvote count as an actual vote in any way --- awarding rep, counting against the 30 vote limit, moving an answer up the page, anything?  Does it "mature" into a real upvote when the user eventually reaches 15 rep?  Searching Meta for "anonymous feedback" is turning up nothing but requests to (de-)anonymize the usual feedback up/down votes, comments, close votes, etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't count as an actual vote in any way, shape, or form- Which is why I didn't post that as an answer. :) It _is_ recorded in the system, it just, as far as I'm aware, isn't used for much if anything. It doesn't mature into a real vote, either. That was more of a "fun fact"/technicality type of thing.

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  I don't have a reference, because I have no idea if it's true.  In fact, Kendra's comment says that it basically _isn't_.  I suggested it as the only way I can imagine the "create posts" page could be correct --- if there were some unstated exception that allowed new users to do as it instructed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New users can certainly click the "upvote" button (and the downvote).

The posts will not get an upvote, but we collect the information as anonymous feedback.

We are teaching them good citizenship - even if it has no effect now, they will know this is what's expected of them.

Comment: Are there any stats on how many users try to vote how many times before earning the vote privilege? Because I didn't know about the anonymous feedback when I started using the site (I assume most people have no idea), and was really put off by the info box that told me I didn't have the voting privilege yet.

Comment: Good question - I don't know that we do have them. You can post a [meta-tag:feature-request] for them.

Comment: Since you have that data, does it make sense to convert those votes once the user achieves the requisite rep... or is it truly anonymized... right in the same bucket with the unregistered users?

Comment: @canon - again, not sure here.

Comment: Apparently, there was a third option...  Should the paragraph I quoted from the "[create posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)" page be modified to let beginners know they'll be casting only pseudo-upvotes until they get 15 reputation?  It would be an unpleasant surprise if a new user upvoted someone as a "thank you", then discovered a few rep points later that it was now impossible to give that person a _real_ upvote (I'm assuming the anonymous feedback would prevent a "second" upvote later).