# Include reputation required to vote in 'Why is voting important' help page

Tags: feature-request, help-center

New to SO and learning about the mechanics of how the site works.

I was looking into voting and read the page [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and came across the line:

> Every user with **sufficient reputation** can exercise their right to vote, every day that they visit the site.

I had to go to the [Privileges Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to find that the sufficient reputation is 15.

Why not include this number in the help page?

Comment: IIRC the reputation levels can vary per site (not that they do at the moment for vote up) while most of the help center pages are static across the network. Maybe a link can be added.

Comment: Fair point, a link could work if the help center pages are static across the network

Comment: *"I had to go to the Privileges Help Page to find that the sufficient reputation is 15."* That depends on the type of vote. Upvotes are 15, downvotes 125, closevotes 3k, delete votes 10k and extended delete votes 20k. (Hope I didn't miss any.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen the help page *why is voting important* only mentions up and down voting. But you're right, one link would not be sufficient.

Comment: Why not link directly to the "Privileges Help Page"? That way all types of votes would be covered.

Comment: Related: Accepted answer to "[Docs for “create posts” and “vote up” privileges contradict each other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320036/4116239)".  Upvotes (and downvotes?) from low-rep users and guests will be recorded, but won't change anyone's reputation score.

Comment: Now you read the Privileges Help Page too. That's a good thing. ;)

Comment: @Trozza Now you have a rep of more than 15 !!!

Comment: @BaummitAugen I suppose there's also tag synonym votes and votes for moderator elections and reviewing is "kind of voting" - maybe could extend that to chat flags as well ;-)